# Can't bind to the keydown event using jayq

Tags: jquery, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to use jayq to allow me to use jquery with clojurescript.

For some reason this code works.

```
(bind ($ :#canvas) :mousedown
      (fn []
        (.log js/console (str "Why mouse but no keys?"))))
```

but this code doesn't.

```
(bind ($ :#canvas) :keydown
      (fn []
        (.log js/console (str "hit"))))
```

Is there any reason why the keydown event isn't caught properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make the canvas focusable, otherwise it won't receive any events. To do that, just give it a tabstop:

```
<canvas id="canvas" tabindex="1" />
```